# View logging info in log console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I've added some `logging.debug` statements to get some more information about where I'm having a problem setting up an endpoint, but I have not been able to get the dev server to show the logs.

I'm trying to update the application settings from the Launcher as mentioned in one of the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982959/getting-logging-debug-to-work-on-google-app-engine-python).  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the Launcher is actually adding the extra command line flag I'm including, `--log_level=debug`, because the log console is not showing any additional information when I test the endpoints on my dev server.  I've tried adding the extra command line flag both before and after using Launcher to run the app, and access the dev server.

I also saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=444bQ3fk7M0) on YouTube.  I'm running Windows (he's on Mac in the video), but I tried what he does just in case, by adding `--debug`, but that didn't do anything either.

Initially, I was trying to download the logs with the help of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229293/download-log-from-appengine-including-python-log-statements), but it seems my command line skills are lacking, because I couldn't get that to work and it kept insisting that I wasn't specifying the directory, which is why I'm trying to do this through the Launcher.

The GAE docs said the regular Python logging module works, so I'm just using that.  I'll be happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: At least on linux the actual cmdline (with all options) used to start the server is printed when the server starts, so one can immediately confirm if various options are set or not. It *might* apply to the windows version as well.

Comment: As a workaround/until you get `logging.debug` to work you can use `logging.error` (by default displayed) instead of `logging.debug` (by default not displayed). This should confirm if your problem is indeed caused by the default logging level or if you should look somewhere else.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, thank you.  I never noticed before, but it does show the command on Windows as well.  Indeed, it isn't setting that option.  Your workaround did the trick for now, though, so thank you very much for that.